# Where does the symbol $\mathcal O$ for sheaves come from?

Tags: terminology, math-history, sheaf-theory

Sheafs are often denoted by the letter $\mathcal O$. What does this O stand for? To me it seems that more natural choices of symbols for sheaves would be $\mathcal S$ or $\mathcal F$ (for the french *faisceau*).

Comment: My guess. From the symbol for holomorphic functions.

Comment: And where does *that* come from?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92135/etymology-of-the-o-notation-for-algebras-of-holomorphic-functions

Comment: @Brad I think this answers my question. Could you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the historical footnote in Grauert/Remmert, Coherent Analytic Sheaves, concerning the origin of the notation $\mathcal{O}$ for the rings of holomorphic functions (and their associated sheaves):

> Some people think the symbol $\mathcal{O}$ was chosen in honor of [Oka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiyoshi_Oka), sometimes it is even said that $\mathcal{O}$ reflects the French pronunciation of *holomorphe*. The truth is that the symbol was chosen accidentally. In a letter to the authors from March 22, 1982, [H. Cartan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Cartan) writes: "Je m'étais simplement inspiré d'une notation utilisée par [van der Waerden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden) dans son classique traité 'Moderne Algebra' (cf. par exemple §16 de la 2e édition allemande, p.52)"

Comment: And why did van der Waerden use it?

Comment: Presumably because Dedekind used $\mathfrak{o}$ for an [order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28ring_theory%29) ("Ordnung" in German). But that may also be idle speculation, I don't know why.

Comment: I just learned from Keith Conrad at HSM that your speculation about order is correct: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/who-first-introduced-the-notation-mathcalo-in-algebraic-geometry-or-algebra/2924?noredirect=1

Comment: For those who are curious, van der Waerden _Moderne Algebra_, 2nd German edition, §16, begins with "let $\mathfrak{o}$ be a ring".